# Post запрос чтение массивов

Tags: массивы, post, golang

На странице tmpl документа, есть форма:

```
<form id="createform" name="createform"  action="/clickCreateRashod" method="post">
        <div class="col-lg-6">  
        <input id="first" name="first" value="Name1">
        <input id="first" name="first" value="Name2">
        <input id="first" name="first" value="Name3">
        <input id="two" name="two" value="5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" >Add</button>
</form>
```

Дак вот как мне в gin получить значения всех трех "first"
Функция обработчик:

```
r.POST("/clickCreateRashod", clickCreateRashodHandle)

func clickCreateRashodHandle(c *gin.Context) {
    //Тут я писал уже кучу всего, как сделать правильно?
}
```

Для одиночного значения c.PostForm("first"), как считать все в массив? Так же можно привести пример из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: три элемента с одинаковым id? интересно.

Comment: Для справки, можешь их убрать, go интересны только name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу у gin подобных методов, но вообще это делается через [`http.(*Request).ParseForm`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) и считывание напрямую из `http.Request.Form` по ключу:

```
r := c.Request
err := r.ParseForm()
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
fmt.Println(r.Form["first"])
```